# Hosting dns nameserver on windows azure (VM)

Tags: windows, azure, dns, azure-virtual-machine, nameservers

I'd like to host my own DNS name server to have total control on the DNS settings.

Is it a good idea to create a Windows 2012 VM (Iaas) on Windows Azure and use it as a DNS name server?

Problems I forsee:

1. Windows Azure SLA requires at least two instances? Not really a problem if the VM is down for < 20min since DNS should be cached downstream.
2. Azure VM Size? Extra small should do.
3. Changing IPs? Once you have the VM set up, Azure should not change your IP address unless you delete it.
4. Reverse DNS? I don't think hosting a nameserver requires a reverse IP DNS lookup.
5. Anything else? not really knowledgeable about hosting a DNS server, but I think it should work!

What am I missing?

Comment: Personally, I think you should do this as a learning experience so you can be comfortable with the answers to all of these questions, and be aware of the other questions you should be asking. You should likely NOT go into this blind!

Answer (score 1):

1. Azure IaaS VMs have an SLA with a single instance, so you wouldn't need to worry about that.
2. Don't use extra-small for anything except development and testing. Network performance is erratic, ranging from very poor to non-existent.
3. The IP address will remain constant while the VM is deployed, yes.

However...
Are you talking about an internal DNS server, or a public nameserver? If the latter, hosting in a cloud datacenter is probably not the best approach. You'd be better off using a dedicated DNS provider like Zerigo.

Comment: The IP address will remain constant while the VM is deployed - Usually yes, but during recovery it may change. Azure does not allow for truly static IPs.